# create database using C#?

Tags: ms-access, c#-4.0

is it possible to create access database on a c:\ drive on the click event of the button ???

Comment: Create from scratch? Or from an existing one? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a Microsoft Jet (Access) database without an interop assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155848/how-do-i-create-a-microsft-jet-access-database-without-an-interop-assembly)

Comment: Depends on where on the C: drive. In the root, you'd likely not be able to because of restrictions on write permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  But this is a duplicate.

To create an **Access** database from C# code use ADOX:
- [How to create an Access database by using ADOX and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317881):

```
using System;
using ADOX;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ADOX.CatalogClass cat = new ADOX.CatalogClass();

            cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                   "Data Source=D:\\AccessDB\\NewMDB.mdb;" +
                   "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");

            Console.WriteLine("Database Created Successfully");

            cat = null;

        }
    }
}
```

[To create an **SQL Server** database from C# code use [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)]

Comment: He is looking to create an _access_ database, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You could use office automation to create a new database and save it to the local drive.

Or if you have a template of a database you could use that and copy it to the local drive.

Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do, a more useful answer can't be given.

Comment: Why would anybody use automation to create it when you've got Jet available on every copy of Windows since 2000? +1 for the template, though.